# Por que al eliminar me duplica el objeto?

Tags: java

tengo este código en una clase y desde el main los mando a imprimir pero al momento de eliminar un objeto con un método me lo duplica llevo poco tiempo en java y lo que se es muy poco.

```
ArrayList<Object> relojesYradioreloj = new ArrayList<>();

    Reloj rl = new Reloj(0, 0, 0); // estos son objetos de otra clase
    Reloj rl1 = new Reloj(20, 59, 57);
    Reloj rl2 = new Reloj(12, 45, 20);



public void imprimirRadioReloj(){


    RadioReloj radiorlj = new RadioReloj("Azul", 1.5, true, rl);
    RadioReloj radiorlj2 = new RadioReloj("Verde", 1.0, false, rl1);
    RadioReloj radiorlj3 = new RadioReloj("Rojo", 1.8, true, rl2);

    relojesYradioreloj.add(radiorlj);
    relojesYradioreloj.add(radiorlj2);
    relojesYradioreloj.add(radiorlj3);
    
    for(int i=0; i<relojesYradioreloj.size(); i ++){
        System.out.println(relojesYradioreloj.get(i));
    }
    
    eliminarRelojes();
}

public void eliminarRelojes(){
    relojesYradioreloj.remove(1);
}
```

Este es parte del el main

```
       int opcion = 0;
    
    while(opcion != 4){
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();  
            if(opcion == 1){
                System.out.println("Hora");
                radio.imprimirRadioReloj();
                radio.eliminarRelojes();
                System.out.println("-----------------------------");

            }else if(opcion == 2){
                System.out.println("Radio Reloj");
                radio.imprimirRadioReloj()
```

esta es la salida, me duplica todo yo espero que me devuelva solo los dos objetos que quedarian.

```
Color: Azul, Peso: 1.5, Original: true, Reloj: 00:00:03 Am
Color: Verde, Peso: 1.0, Original: false, Reloj: 20:59:59 Pm
Color: Rojo, Peso: 1.8, Original: true, Reloj: 12:45:22 Am
Color: Azul, Peso: 1.5, Original: true, Reloj: 00:00:04 Am
Color: Verde, Peso: 1.0, Original: false, Reloj: 21:00:00 Pm
Color: Rojo, Peso: 1.8, Original: true, Reloj: 12:45:23 Am
```

Comment: En el metodo **imprimirRadioReloj** agrega 3 instancias "literales" de la clase RadioReloj (a traves de las variables locales) radiorlj, radiorlj2, radiorlj antes de imprimir con el for. Por eso esta duplicando la informacion.

Comment: pero cuando elijo la opción 1 del main me imprime los 3 elementos de la lista cuando vuelvo a presionar 1 me borra el elemento que esta en el indice 1 y me imprime otros 3 elementos nuevamente y en total tendria 5 elementos impresos y yo solo quiero que me imprima los elementos que queden en la lista.

Comment: Lo que yo veo es que en el metodo **imprimirRadioReloj** agrega 3 instancias a la lista. De esta manera cada vez que invoque **imprimirRadioReloj** agrega tres instancias. No deberia agregarle elementos a la lista en ese metodo sino solo hacer el for para imprimirlas.

Comment: Tampoco me suena que en la logica de la opcion dos primero invoca el metodo **imprimirRadioReloj** antes que el metodo **eliminarRelojes** es decir esta imprimiendo antes de eliminar ... como espera que visualice el resultado de la eliminación?

Comment: tuve que crear otro metodo que se llama agregar y desde ahi agregue los elementos a la lista luego mande a llamar el metodo desde el main pero fuera del while y me funciono, pero nose por que la clase no me deja agregar elementos a la lista fuera de la clase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imprime después de eliminar ya que si imprimes antes de eliminar estás imprimiendo como si no hubieras hecho nada:

```
public void imprimirRadioReloj(){


    RadioReloj radiorlj = new RadioReloj("Azul", 1.5, true, rl);
    RadioReloj radiorlj2 = new RadioReloj("Verde", 1.0, false, rl1);
    RadioReloj radiorlj3 = new RadioReloj("Rojo", 1.8, true, rl2);

    relojesYradioreloj.add(radiorlj);
    relojesYradioreloj.add(radiorlj2);
    relojesYradioreloj.add(radiorlj3);
    
    eliminarRelojes();

    for(int i=0; i<relojesYradioreloj.size(); i ++){
        System.out.println(relojesYradioreloj.get(i));
    }
    
}
```

Se imprime dos veces porque en el main en la opción 1 lo imprimes y en la llamada al método se imprime nuevamente. Podrías quitar la de main, y que el método al eliminar imprima el resultado:

```
while(opcion != 4){
            opcion = teclado.nextInt();  
            if(opcion == 1){
                System.out.println("Hora");
                radio.eliminarRelojes();
                System.out.println("-----------------------------");

            }else if(opcion == 2){
                System.out.println("Radio Reloj");
                radio.imprimirRadioReloj()
```

Recomiendo que añadas mejor un método de agregar, uno de eliminar, y que esos relojes dentro de la clase reloj estén en un arrayList como campo de la clase radio, para que todos los métodos tengan acceso y para que halla mejor control.